# Фон изображением в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer, qss

Сам внешний вид делаю в `QT Designer`, создал файл стилей и установил фоновое изображение как `background-image: url(:/background/2.jpg);` в самом `MainWindow`, но вместе с этим все кнопки и остальные виджеты тоже окрасились этим фоном, как его оставить только на само окно?

[image: trouble]

ui модуль в коде:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'front.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 400))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 400))
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/background/2.jpg);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnBrowse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 131, 23))
        self.btnBrowse.setObjectName("btnBrowse")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 131, 151))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.btnArch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnArch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 170, 81, 23))
        self.btnArch.setObjectName("btnArch")
        self.browseArch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.browseArch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 0, 131, 23))
        self.browseArch.setObjectName("browseArch")
        self.exlist = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.exlist.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 20, 131, 151))
        self.exlist.setObjectName("exlist")
        self.exButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 170, 91, 23))
        self.exButton.setObjectName("exButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Archivator"))
        self.btnBrowse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать папку"))
        self.btnArch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Архивировать"))
        self.browseArch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать архив"))
        self.exButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Извлечь"))
import res_rc
```

Comment: только для окна стиль назначить, если для главного то `QMainWindow { стиль  }`

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста ваш пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @PavelGridin обновил вопрос, как видно оно для qmainwindow и установлено

Comment: @S.Nick обновил вопрос

Comment: Опубликуйте модуль `.ui`

Comment: Там должно быть `QMainWindow { background-image: url(:/background/2.jpg); }` иначе это назначится всем нижестоящим

Comment: @PavelGridin если делаю таким образом, то картинка маленькой полоской только внизу остается, остальное окно пустое

Comment: это уже другой вопрос

Comment: плюс добавляется импорт ресурсов в конец файла, который тригерит ошибку, а без него фона нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 400))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 400))
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnBrowse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 131, 23))
        self.btnBrowse.setObjectName("btnBrowse")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 131, 151))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.btnArch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnArch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 170, 81, 23))
        self.btnArch.setObjectName("btnArch")
        self.browseArch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.browseArch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 0, 131, 23))
        self.browseArch.setObjectName("browseArch")
        self.exlist = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.exlist.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 20, 131, 151))
        self.exlist.setObjectName("exlist")
        self.exButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 170, 91, 23))
        self.exButton.setObjectName("exButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Archivator"))
        self.btnBrowse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать папку"))
        self.btnArch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Архивировать"))
        self.browseArch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать архив"))
        self.exButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Извлечь"))


class Demo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Demo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setStyleSheet('.QWidget {background-image: url(lena.jpg);}')     # <<<---


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Demo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скопировал ваш код, там где вставка фона написал `self.setStyleSheet('.QWidget {background-image: url(2.jpg);}')` таким образом фона нет, пробовал указывать полный путь, тоже не помогло

Comment: @ClarkDevlin 1. Скопируйте мой пример целиком и запустите, чтобы проверить его работу. 2. Куда вы скопировали и что вы скопировали ?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin для начала положите свое изображение в туже папку что и модуль `.py`. Проверьте - работает ?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin вы задали вопрос, я попросил у вас пример кода. По вашему примеру показал как надо сделать. 1. Мой ответ решил вашу проблему? 2. Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос. Опишите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается и приведите пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Я уже сам разобрался, большое спасибо. А не могли бы объяснить почему именно такой код?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin потому что центральный виджет `self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)`, а `.` перед `QWidget` говорит о том, что стиль должен распространяться только на `QWidget` .и никак не трогать виджеты родителем который он является.

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Зачем вы удалили пост https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1137442/pyqt-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-qdialog ??

Comment: там было достаточно банальное решение, которое просто мне сразу в голову не пришло, извините, если потратил ваше время

Comment: @ClarkDevlin так делать не правильно. В таком случае вы должны были опубликовать свое решение как ответ. Мне жаль потраченного времени, а вы не получили для себя новые навыки.